# Android accessibility service overlay navigation buttons hidden

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibilityservice

I'm currently trying to implement an accessibility service for my app and i'm having trouble with the view. The problem is that when i'm showing my view with the flag overlay:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY
```

The overlay seems to go over the navigation button. I've searched for this issue on here and i've found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58819647/overlay-of-type-type-accessibility-overlay-hides-navigation-buttons/). My problem is EXACTLY the same as this issuer but there's no answer to it.

Thanks